# MATLAB R2013b does not support Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have recently installed VS 2013. I have a .cpp project which I want to compile into mex with MATLAB 2013b. As soon as I enter:

```
mex -setup
```

in MATLAB and then I select "y" for "Would you like mex to locate installed compilers?", I receive the message that: "No supported SDK or compiler was found on this computer."
How can I get around this problem?

Comment: To be tried with caution of course, here are some manually edited options files to add unofficial support for VS2013 in R2013a/b : http://kaba.hilvi.org/homepage/blog/vs2013_in_matlab_2013/vs_2013_in_matlab_2013.htm ... If you can, prefer downgrading VS or upgrading Matlab version as suggested by @rayryeng

Comment: @CitizenInsane - OH YES.  I have seen this post before, but you have to know what you're doing.  I've managed to it working, but I almost screwed up my computer doing it lol.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: @rayryeng Btw, it's quite a shame that  `lcc-x64` is not automatically included with matlab installs (only `lcc-x32` is) ... this would avoid not to omit having to deploy VC redistributables ... may be in next releases ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 is not supported by MATLAB R2013b.  See this link for more details: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013b/.  The latest compiler and environment that R2013b can support for Windows is Visual Studio 2012.  Your options are to either downgrade your version of Visual Studio to one that is compatible on that list I referred you to, or upgrade your version of MATLAB to at least R2014a or higher.